# installing npm packages in laravel application

Tags: php, laravel, npm

i want to deploy my laravel application now and before doing so i just wanted to know about the npm packages do i install them or keep it like it is ?

the app works more than fine without the need to run npm install.

the app size is 20000 pages and if i run npm install it'll be 32000.

any help here what to do? and if i install all the packages what's next what should i do?

```
    "devDependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.18",
    "bootstrap": "^4.1.0",
    "cross-env": "^5.1",
    "jquery": "^3.2",
    "laravel-mix": "^4.0.7",
    "lodash": "^4.17.5",
    "popper.js": "^1.12",
    "resolve-url-loader": "^2.3.1",
    "sass": "^1.15.2",
    "sass-loader": "^7.1.0",
    "vue": "^2.5.17"
}
```

Comment: What is the purpose of all those packages? Have you used any where in your laravel application?

Comment: This is a tool provide by Laravel call Laravel Mix to help you compile and manage your assets. If you don't use it, you don't have to do npm install. Take a look at here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/mix

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The packages that you have shown above are all development dependencies so you need those only on your machine in order to perform development. When you build it later on using `npm run dev` or `npm run prod`, it will get transformed into JS code.

So if you say that it the app works on your production server where you want to deploy the app that means that you have the packages that you use globally accessible on the server, or otherwise it will not work 100%.

So you don't need to run `npm install` because that will install all the `dependencies` along with the `devDependencies`, so you should use `npm install --only=prod` (or `--only=production`) to install only `dependencies`, and not `devDependencies`, regardless of the value of the NODE_ENV environment variable.

**Note: if you don't have `dependencies` in your package.json, then there is no need to do this on production server.**

Comment: thanks. so the next step is npm install --only=prod and then deploy the app ?

Comment: You do this `npm install --only=prod` on your production server, not locally. Because you are not pushing to the repository the `node_modules` folder in which the packages are installed.

Comment: my site will be hosted in hostinger.com i'll upload it without the npm and without node_modules folder. when the uploading is done how do i run the npm install --only=prod command ?

Comment: how are you going to install the `composer` dependencies there? I don't have experience with them, but if you can ssh on the server and install dependencies from your project that's how you should do it. Same as `composer`.